# Error 'WebRTC not supported' while making voice call in react native android

Tags: react-native

I am creating voice call using 'jssip.js' library in react-native. I have created the socket using WebSocketInterface from jssip for a bandwidth account. And also am able to register the sip endpoint using JsSIP.UA method.But when making the call i got error as "WebRTC NOT SUPPORTED". Don't know why this happening.

```
let JsSIP= require('jssip');

let socket = new JsSIP.WebSocketInterface('wss://webrtc.registration.bandwidth.com:10443');

let configuration = { 
            sockets: [socket],
            uri: 'sip:***@****.com',
            password: '********'
        };

let ua = new JsSIP.UA(configuration);

ua.start();

ua.on('unregistered', (call)=>{
            console.log("client unregistered");
        });

ua.on('progress', (call)=>{
            console.log("progress");
        });

ua.on('registered', (call)=>{             
            console.log("client registered");
        });  //I have got this log

let eventHandlers = {
            'progress': function (e) {
                console.log('call is in progress');
            },
            'failed': function (e) {
                console.log('call failed with cause: ');
            }
        };

let option = {
            'eventHandlers': eventHandlers,
            'mediaConstraints': {'audio': true, 'video': false},
            'pcConfig': {rtcpMuxPolicy: 'negotiate'}
        };

ua.call(toNumber, option);
```

Comment: I am getting same issue. Did you find any solution for this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Pooja Patel
Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @Harikishore P Have you find any solution for this I am also getting same error.